# How to link to JavaScript file in node_modules?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to link to `/node_modules/jade/runtime.min.js` client-side -- how do I make it publicly accessible?

Do I create a `app.get` for it somehow?

```
app.get('/js/jade-runtime.js',<what goes here?>)
```

Or can I modify the static thing to allow it to be served?

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); // modify this to add more paths somehow
```

---

#### Full solution (thanks [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14097444/65387)):

```
app.get('/js/jade-runtime.js',function(req,res) {
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname,'node_modules','jade','runtime.min.js'));
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this with your `app.get`.

```
res.sendfile('jade-runtime.js');
```

Obviously, use the correct path to where that file is located.

http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly, thank you! I thought there might be a function like that but I wasn't sure what to look for.

Comment: @Mark, Great!  I'm happy it works for you.  Yes, the Express documentation is a bit difficult to use.  I just started working with it myself earlier this weekend.  I think once I fully understand what all there is to it, I might try to contribute to fixing the docs.  It seems documentation isn't a priority for any of the Node.js-based stuff out there, presumably because the projects are so new and rapidly changing.